# Decrypting PDF-Files

Tags: python, beginner, pdf

In [Encrypt PDF-Files](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/211216/encrypt-pdf-files/211279#211279) I provided a Python program to encrypt PDF-Files in a folder.

This program here does the oposite. Giving a password and path all PDFs which are encrypted are decrypted in the supplied path. If the password is wrong a message is displayed.

**pdf_decrypter.py**

```
"""
Decrypts all files in a folder and sub folder with provided password
"""

import os
import argparse
from typing import Tuple
from getpass import getpass
from pathlib import Path
import PyPDF2

def get_password_from_user() -> str:
    """Asks the user to enter a password"""
    while True:
        password: str = getpass(promt="Enter password: ")
        if password:
            return password


def get_path_from_user() -> str:
    """Asks for a path from the User"""
    while True:
        #input_string = "E:/Python Projekte\ATBS\CH13_EX1_pdf_decrypter\CH13_EX1_pdf_decrypter\CH13_EX1_pdf_decrypter\\testfolder"
        path = Path(input("Enter absolute Path:"))
        if os.path.exists(path):
            return path
        print("Path doesn't exist\n")


def get_path_and_password() -> Tuple[str, str]:
    """
    Gets path and password from command line or
    if not available from the user
    """
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument(
        "--path", help="provide root folder to look for PDFs to encrypt",
        type=str)
    parser.add_argument(
        "--password", help="password to encrypt PDFs with", type=str)
    args = parser.parse_args()
    if args.path and args.password:
        return Path(args.path), args.password
    return get_path_from_user(), get_password_from_user()


def is_encrypted(filename: str) -> bool:
    """Checks if file is encrypted"""
    with open(filename, 'rb') as pdf_file:
        pdf_reader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdf_file)
        return pdf_reader.isEncrypted


def decrypt(filename: str, password: str) -> bool:
    """
    Try to decrypt a file. If not successful a false is returned.
    If the file passed is not encrypted also a false is passed
    """
    with open(filename, 'rb') as pdf_file:
        pdf_reader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdf_file)
        pdf_reader.decrypt(password)
        pdf_writer = PyPDF2.PdfFileWriter()

        try:
            for page_number in range(pdf_reader.numPages):
                pdf_writer.addPage(pdf_reader.getPage(page_number))
        except PyPDF2.utils.PdfReadError:
            return False

        filename_decrypted = filename.strip('.pdf') + "_decrypted.pdf"

        with open(filename_decrypted, 'wb') as pdf_file_decrypted:
            pdf_writer.write(pdf_file_decrypted)
    return True


def pdf_decrypter():
    """
    Main routine:
    Giving a password and path all PDFs which are encrypted get 
    decrypted in the supplied path. 
    If the password is wrong a message is displayed.
    """
    path, password = get_path_and_password()
    for folder_name, _, filenames in os.walk(path):
        for filename in filenames:
            if not filename.endswith('.pdf'):
                continue

            if not is_encrypted(os.path.join(folder_name, filename)):
                continue

            if decrypt(os.path.join(folder_name, filename), password):
                os.remove(filename)
            else:
                print(filename + " could not be decrypted (wrong password)")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    pdf_decrypter()
```

I already incorporated improvements suggested in the encrypter review in [Encrypt PDF-Files](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/211216/encrypt-pdf-files/211279#211279)

What else can be improved in the code?

Let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Bugs:

1. Here, instead of `promt` it should be `prompt`:

   > ```
   > password: str = getpass(promt="Enter password: ")
   > ```
2. If PDF file is not in the current folder, this will throw an error:

   > ```
   > if decrypt(os.path.join(folder_name, filename), password):
   >     os.remove(filename)
   > ```

   it should be `os.remove(os.path.join(folder_name, filename))` instead.

#### Docstring:

> ```
> """
> Decrypts all files in a folder and sub folder with provided password
> """
> ```

I think it would be better to specify that only PDF files will be decrypted. Also, it should mention that original copy will be removed. How about:

```
"""
Decrypts all pdf files in a specified folder
and all its sub-folders with provided password,
saves decrypted copy and removes original encrypted files.
"""
```

#### [PEP 8:](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

> Imports should be grouped in the following order:
>
> 1. Standard library imports.
> 2. Related third party imports.
> 3. Local application/library specific imports.
>
> You should put a blank line between each group of imports.

Also, it is advised to sort imports [alphabetically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20762662/whats-the-correct-way-to-sort-python-import-x-and-from-x-import-y-statement).

So, instead of:

> ```
> import os
> import argparse
> from typing import Tuple
> from getpass import getpass
> from pathlib import Path
> import PyPDF2
> ```

You will have:

```
import argparse
import os
from getpass import getpass
from pathlib import Path
from typing import Tuple

import PyPDF2
```

Also, before the first function there should be two [blank lines](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#blank-lines). Apart from that, well done! You follow the style guide pretty well!

#### [Click:](https://click.palletsprojects.com)

Instead of using argparse, I'd suggest to take a look at third-party library Click. [Why Click?](http://click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/why/)

**Example of usage:**
For example, here is how you could wrap main function `pdf_decrypter`:

```
import click

...

@click.command()
@click.option('--path', '-p',
              default='.',
              show_default=True,
              type=click.Path(),
              help='Folder path to look for PDFs to decrypt '
                   '(absolute or relative).')
@click.password_option(confirmation_prompt=False)
def pdf_decrypter(path: str,
                  password: str):
...
```

Running `python3 pdf_decrypter.py --help` from command line will print:

```
Usage: pdf_decrypter.py [OPTIONS]

  Main routine: Giving a password and path all PDFs which are encrypted get
  decrypted in the supplied path. If the password is wrong a message is
  displayed.

Options:
  -p, --path PATH  Folder path to look for PDFs to decrypt (absolute or
                   relative). [default: .]
  --password TEXT
  --help           Show this message and exit.
```

**Confirmation messages:**
Further in the body of the function you can add confirmation message as well, like:

```
...
if not click.confirm(f'All PDF files will be encrypted in {path}\n'
                     'Do you want to continue?'):
    return
...
```

This will look like:

```
python3 pdf_decrypter.py 
Password: 
All PDF files will be encrypted in /path/to/pdf_files
Do you want to continue? [y/N]:
```

**Putting encryption and decryption together:**
And, probably, you would want to put both encryption from your previous post and decryption in the same module later, as they share a lot in common. In this case you would want to use [Nesting Commands](http://click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/quickstart/#nesting-commands), for example, like this:

```
@click.group()
def cli():
    pass


@cli.command()
@click.option('--path', '-p',
              default='.',
              show_default=True,
              type=click.Path(),
              help='Folder path to look for PDFs to decrypt '
                   '(absolute or relative).')
@click.password_option(confirmation_prompt=False)
def decrypt(path: str,
            password: str):
...

@cli.command()
@click.option('--path', '-p',
              default='.',
              show_default=True,
              type=click.Path(),
              help='Folder path to look for PDFs to decrypt '
                   '(absolute or relative).')
@click.password_option(confirmation_prompt=False)
def encrypt(path: str,
            password: str) -> None:
...
```

And you would call your functions like `python pdf_utils.py encrypt` or `python pdf_utils.py decrypt`, etc.

[**`click.Path`:**](http://click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/api/#click.Path)
You can specify additional checks, like checking if path exists, path is not a file, and also make Click to resolve path automatically by setting `resolve_path` as `True`. So you wouldn't have to use `os.path.join` later in the code:

```
@click.option('--path', '-p',
              default='.',
              show_default=True,
              type=click.Path(exists=True,
                              file_okay=False,
                              resolve_path=True),
              help='Folder path to look for PDFs to decrypt '
                   '(absolute or relative).')
```

#### Iterating over files:

Right now you have two nested loops and two checks of extension and if file is encrypted:

> ```
> for folder_name, _, filenames in os.walk(path):
>     for filename in filenames:
>         if not filename.endswith('.pdf'):
>             continue
>
>         if not is_encrypted(os.path.join(folder_name, filename)):
>             continue
>
>         # decryption logic
> ```

This looks pretty cumbersome. And I personally don't like it when the code is nested on two or more levels. We can use [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) module to simplify this logic:

```
pdf_paths = Path(path).rglob('*.pdf')
encrypted_pdfs = filter(is_encrypted, pdf_paths)
for pdf in encrypted_pdfs:
    # decryption logic
```

#### Errors catching:

Now you catch `PyPDF2.utils.PdfReadError` on the deepest level, in `decrypt` function. I suggest you to take it out to main function, and not return `True` or `False` to indicate success/failure. See, for example, [When and how should I use exceptions?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/219320/when-and-how-should-i-use-exceptions)
So, in the `pdf_decrypter`, you will have:

```
for pdf in encrypted_pdfs:
    try:
        decrypt(pdf, password)
        pdf.unlink()
    except PyPDF2.utils.PdfReadError:
        print(f'{pdf} could not be decrypted (wrong password)')
```

#### `pathlib` over `os`:

You almost don't use advantages of the `pathlib`. I already included some things in previous code examples. But here I will sum up everything.

**Opening file:**
This:

> ```
> with open(filename, 'rb') as pdf_file:
> ```

will become:

```
with filepath.open('rb') as pdf_file:
```

Note that `filepath` would be a better name here.

**Changing filename:**

> ```
> filename_decrypted = filename.strip('.pdf') + "_decrypted.pdf"
> ```

could be rewritten as:

```
decrypted_filename = f'{filepath.stem}_decrypted{filepath.suffix}'  # new name
decrypted_filepath = filepath.parent / decrypted_filename  # complete path
```

**Removing file:**
`os.remove(path)` can be replaced by `path.unlink()`.
By this moment we removed all `os` module usages. So, we can remove that import.

#### Putting it all together:

```
"""
Decrypts or encrypts all pdf files in a specified folder
and all its sub-folders with provided password,
saves processed copies and removes original files.
"""
from itertools import filterfalse
from pathlib import Path

import click
import PyPDF2


def is_encrypted(filepath: Path) -> bool:
    """Checks if file is encrypted"""
    with filepath.open('rb') as pdf_file:
        pdf_reader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdf_file)
        return pdf_reader.isEncrypted


def write_copy(filepath: Path,
               password: str,
               *,
               mode: str) -> None:
    """
    Writes encrypted or decrypted copy of the file based on the mode
    :param filepath: path of the PDF file to be processed
    :param password: password to decrypt/encrypt PDF with
    :param mode: one of 'encrypt' or 'decrypt'
    """
    with filepath.open('rb') as pdf_file:
        pdf_reader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdf_file)
        pdf_writer = PyPDF2.PdfFileWriter()

        if mode == 'decrypt':
            pdf_reader.decrypt(password)
        for page_number in range(pdf_reader.numPages):
            pdf_writer.addPage(pdf_reader.getPage(page_number))
        if mode == 'encrypt':
            pdf_writer.encrypt(password)

        suffix = {'decrypt': '_decrypted',
                  'encrypt': '_encrypted'}
        processed_filename = f'{filepath.stem}{suffix[mode]}{filepath.suffix}'
        processed_filepath = filepath.parent / processed_filename

        with processed_filepath.open('wb') as pdf_file_processed:
            pdf_writer.write(pdf_file_processed)


@click.group()
def cli():
    pass


@cli.command()
@click.option('--path', '-p',
              default='.',
              show_default=True,
              type=click.Path(exists=True,
                              file_okay=False,
                              resolve_path=True),
              help='Folder path to look for PDFs to decrypt '
                   '(absolute or relative).')
@click.password_option(confirmation_prompt=False)
def decrypt(path: str,
            password: str) -> None:
    """
    Decrypts all encrypted PDFs in the supplied path.
    If the password is wrong a message is displayed.
    Saves processed copies and removes original files.
    :param path: folder path to look for PDFs to decrypt
    :param password: password to decrypt PDFs with
    """
    pdf_paths = Path(path).rglob('*.pdf')
    encrypted_pdfs = filter(is_encrypted, pdf_paths)
    for pdf in encrypted_pdfs:
        try:
            write_copy(pdf, password, mode='decrypt')
            pdf.unlink()
            click.echo(f'Decrypted successfully: {pdf}')
        except PyPDF2.utils.PdfReadError:
            click.echo(f'{pdf} could not be decrypted (wrong password)')


@cli.command()
@click.option('--path', '-p',
              default='.',
              show_default=True,
              type=click.Path(exists=True,
                              file_okay=False,
                              resolve_path=True),
              help='Folder path to look for PDFs to decrypt '
                   '(absolute or relative).')
@click.password_option(confirmation_prompt=False)
def encrypt(path: str,
            password: str) -> None:
    """
    Encrypts all non-encrypted PDFs in the supplied path.
    Saves processed copies and removes original files.
    :param path: folder path to look for PDFs to encrypt
    :param password: password to encrypt PDFs with
    """
    if not click.confirm(f'All PDF files will be encrypted in {path}\n'
                         'Do you want to continue?'):
        return

    pdf_paths = Path(path).rglob('*.pdf')
    not_encrypted_pdfs = filterfalse(is_encrypted, pdf_paths)

    for pdf in not_encrypted_pdfs:
        write_copy(pdf, password, mode='encrypt')
        pdf.unlink()
        click.echo(f'Encrypted successfully: {pdf}')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    cli()
```

Probably, `encrypt` and `decrypt` could be put in one function with a `mode` parameter, like what I did in a `write_copy` function; but see for yourself if it will make the code more clear.